How to do the element wise multiplication with sample size as first dimension?
I have two matrices with size of (100,150,1000) and (100,150) where 100 is the sample size and 150 rows and 1000 columns. I can use A*B for one value such as (150,1000) and (150) but I want to speed up the computation for 100 sample size. I am not sure how to do it efficiently.
Thanks in advance
I have tried A*B with size as (150,1000) and (150)

Have you tried something like A * B[:, np.newaxis, :] ?

The basic rule of broadcasting is that new leading dimensions are automatic, but trailing dimensions need to be explcit.  So to match (100,150,1000), the other needs to be (100,150,1).  Get that with reshape or a [:,:,None] indexing.  Size 1 dimensions are scaled to match.

Given that this is Numpy, I believe it is considered good practice to use [:,:,np.newaxis] to leave the intention explicit, but it isn't actually required.

Thank you @Nick ODell. I have tried A * B[:, :,np.newaxis] and worked. Thanks. Please add it as answer and I will accept it.

Thank you@David.  I have used the same. Got the idea from Nick. Thank you
